# Setting up a single driver to be automatically compiled with DKMS from kernel tree

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, bluetooth, dkms

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with the HWE from Vivid, meaning I'm running kernel 3.19 for now, until 15.10 hits and the kernel is made available through HWE.

I'm on a MacBook Pro and my particular Bluetooth device isn't recognized by [btusb.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/tree/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c) as it's not in the recognized device list. My device info is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x05ac Apple, Inc.
  idProduct          0x8290 
  bcdDevice            1.04
  iManufacturer           1 Broadcom Corp.
  iProduct                2 Bluetooth USB Host Controller
```

I've verified that it's not wrking and that the device isn't detected, and I believe this change would fix it.

What I'd need to do is get the source tree for my particular branch of linux, download it into `/usr/src`, register it as a DKMS module, and have it automatically build btusb.ko on each kernel install and insert it in there.

What I'm not clear on is that the kernel already ships with btusb, and I'm not sure if the newly compiled module will overwrite the kernel-provided one or not. Is there a straightforward way to do this? And in the kernel Makefiles, is there a way to have it only compile the btusb driver without having to compile the entire kernel? Is there a better, more straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have already done a DKMS version of the patched btusb.c for the 3.19 kernel

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/47u2zjrkqvkf1tw/btusbmac-dkms_1.6_all.deb
dpkg -i btusbmac-dkms_1.6_all.deb
```

Reboot

If you want to see the source code, you can right click on the deb file and select 'open with archive manager' then extract the files.  You will likely have to right click on the folder to change the permissions so that you can read the files in /usr/src/btusbmac-1.6

Tested and confirmed [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=206300)

Comment: Great. Are your patches the latest from bluetooth-next? The latest ones should allow other Bluetooth devices to function. Also, any luck with the keyboard and trackpad?

Comment: No they aren't, I will check out the bluetooth-next tree

Comment: Can you DM message me on Twitter so we can talk offline about setting up a PPA with awesome packages like this? I've written some DKMS stuff for other things too. [@rfkrocktk](https://twitter.com/rfkrocktk)

Comment: I am not on twitter but github might be easier than setting up a PPA

Comment: Please contact me over GitHub so we can get it set up: https://github.com/rfkrocktk/

Comment: I was able to set github to follow you but don't see a link for contact

Comment: I have setup a repository for this code here: https://github.com/rfkrocktk/macbook-btusb-trusty